# Cannot access non-static field "Repeater" in static context

Tags: html, .net, static, repeater, httpcontext

I have a web page in one web forms project where I use a Repeater; this is the code on the page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Event">
            <div class="">
                <h3><a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Url") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></a></h3>
                <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Location") %>. <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateDisplay") %></span>
                &nbsp;
            </div>

        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and here's the codebehind:

```
    namespace TestWebForms
{
    public partial class EventSearchResults : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string searchTerms { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var query = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;

            var searchTerms = String.IsNullOrEmpty(query["q"]) ? String.Empty : query["q"]; 

            ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

            values.Add(new Event()
            {
                Name = "Class of 1715 300th Reunion",
                Location = "Cambridge, MA",
                DateDisplay = "May 20th 2015",
                Url = "#"
            });
            values.Add(new Event()
            {
                Name = "Symposium on Proper Cat Petting Techniques",
                Location = "Boston, MA",
                DateDisplay = "December 25th 2014",
                Url = "#"
            });
            values.Add(new Event()
            {
                Name = "Puppies Everywhere!!!",
                Location = "Cambridge, MA",
                DateDisplay = "November 12th 2014",
                Url = "#"
            });

            Repeater1.DataSource = values;
            Repeater1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

It worked fine.

Then I copied and pasted everything into files in a new project (long story, but basically I need the files to exist in project 2 but I'm unable to view the site in project 2, so I created the page I needed in project 1 in order to view it and then copied it over to project 2 when it was done)

The files are literally exactly the same (other than the namespace of the webpage). But the repeater isn't working in project 2. In the codebehind, Repeater1 has a red underline and it says "Cannot access non-static field "Repeater" in static context."

How can I fix this, and why on earth would it work in one project but not the other?

Comment: Cant think why it would cause that error, but have you got a EventSearchResults.aspx.designer.cs file and if so, have you also changed the namespace in there?

Comment: no, I don't have that file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, when I copied it over to a new file, the new file that was created was using "CodeFile" instead of "CodeBehind". Changing it to CodeBehind fixed the problem

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EventSearchResults.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAssets_Templates_EventSearchResults" %>
```

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer by clicking the "tick". This reomved the question from the pool of unanswered questions.